# How Do I Compile Multiple Applications To Custom Locations In One ActionScript Project?

Tags: actionscript, flash-builder

I would like to be able to debug / run my ActionScript project in Flash Builder and have it compile the multiple applications (SWFs) in the project, placing the SWFs in the locations I designate.

When I add all of my application classes to the project configuration and run the project, all SWFs are compiled and everything works. But I don't want all of the SWFs dumped into the root of my build directory.

So I right click one of the runnable classes, choose "Properties", and update the Run/Debug Settings to the location I want. Then it stops compiling that SWF.

I've used Clean and Build All to no effect.

The -o and -output parameters are no longer available in the compiler settings in Flash Builder 4.6. And I'd rather not use Ant while I'm developing.

Anybody know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have multiple "Main" classes in the same project?  I would split them out into separate projects and set the output directory on each one.

If they share code, the shared code should be moved into its own project as an actionscript library.  Projects that depend on that library need to have their properties changed.  You can specify what dependencies a project has on another project through the libraries tab I believe.

Run/debug settings do not affect the directory that the project outputs to.  After each of your project compiles into its specified output directory, it will then attempt to run the project in the directory you specified.

Comment: Thanks, badunk. I do not have multiple "Main" classes, and I'm not interested in creating a separate project for every SWF in my project.

I see that changing the run/debug settings only changes what file is opened after a build. The information I'm looking for is how to change the location and file name of each SWF compiled.

Comment: I believe it should be in the properties.  Maybe this will help: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingFlashBuilder/WS6f97d7caa66ef6eb1e63e3d11b6c4d0d21-7feb.html#WS6f97d7caa66ef6eb1e63e3d11b6c4d0d21-7f89